# Which language should i use for store the test data?

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, database, capstone

I will create an mobile app for my capstone project. Firstly, we will implement an app and fix the phone on the wall like smart house systems.This app will measure seismic waves. After we measure the data, we will store and show with graphs etc. in a web app. Here is my question, We aren't very good at this actually, how we can build this app, which language is best for us? Can it be done with just react and sql?

Comment: You can go with React Native. Also libraries like ChartJS will help you.

Comment: For a web app, I'd say React Native is not neccessary and involves a little extra complicity. While ChartJS is a great suggestion for out of the box visualisation of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the short answer is yes.

Though my recommendation, as a developer who's worked with numeraous frameworks and languages, would be Vue instead of React as it is much more beginner friendly paired with php written backend, not only because of its pretty easy to get into, but it can also be deployed on practivally any type of server or webhost.

I once made a file-system db with 30 lines of code storing .json files. though in your case sql would be much more suitable, but would require a bit more than that.

Comment: Though if you do want the latest in tech and want to keep your hair during debugging, I'd recommend ELM followed by GO written backend. But requires a lot more to get into ofcourse.

Comment: thanks for your response. Do you have any suggestion for mobile framework for measuring the waves?

Comment: How are you planning on collecting the data?

Comment: we thought to use android's gyroscope, accelerometer etc. and manipulate these kits.Also someone told us the phone microphones can detect small waves and can be suitable for measuring.

Comment: Do you intend for the data collection to be done in session by hand or by an ever present kit for a constinuous workload, I'm thinking power consuption.

Comment: Although that might not matter that much on the other hand, if the application is installed and run natively. I'd still recommend Vue as it does offer some options for mobile runtime, like Capacitor. take a look here: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/mobile.html#introduction .. otherwise C# is a great language for an all purpouse platform. but be prepaired to redo your first or second attempt

Comment: phone will be fixed the wall, connected to wall plug, so always on charge. This projects goal is like reuse old smartphones with this project.

Comment: alright, smart. the simplest setup would consist of three applications. a native, mobile one utilizing the phones gyro, mic etc. so that the phone can be asleep and still gather that data. a backend to store and preferably process it and one for its visualization. I'd still recomment Vue, Capacitor and PHP. atleast to start with. Do keep in mind though that all phones are build different and will yield varying data on the same stream.

Comment: ok then, thanks a lot.

Comment: no worries =) I'd appreciate an upvote and an acception of the answer